# ssh forwarding to guest vm on Mac

Tags: ssh

I would like to know the ssh command for the following diagram:
[image: OSX Host with Windows VM running listener program]
such that I can type `telnet <osxipaddr> 7777` on external computer and have it connect to the program listening on port 1020.

I would also like to be able to type that same telnet command on OSXHost to connect to the program as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called Local port forwarding and the command for example is

```
ssh -NfTL *:7777:windows-ip:1020 localhost
```

Or you can do the same using `netcat` or `iptables`.

Comment: sorry, it should have been `-N` (uppercase).